# How should I set up my partitions when installing Ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, hard-drive, root

I am trying to make my laptop dual boot with Windows 10 and Ubuntu. My laptop is having 8 GB ram and a 1 TB hard disk. The max I can devote to Ubuntu is 250 GB.

Now I am trying to understand clearly how much space needs to be allocated to each mount point. Below are the few points I understood

1. `/swap` :- used to move files if RAM runs out. It should be greater than 2XRAM. So I can dedicate 16 GB.
2. `/root`  :- It is like Local Disk C in Windows. It stores all the Ubuntu OS files. I can put 30 GB under it.
3. `/home` :- It will be hard drive for my Ubuntu. So rest all can be put in here.

Now some instructions are telling me to create a partition for `/` . I tried to read & it was written that this partition stores programme files. I am not able to understand the difference between `/` & `/root`. Can anyone please once explain the difference to me and also how much space I should allot to it & even if other partitions need more or less space.

Thank you.

Comment: I am not able to understand what it meant by saying "/root is the home folder for the 'root' user" . What is meant by root user and there is already a /home folder so am bit confused.

Comment: You do not need a swap partition.  You also don't **need** a separate home partition. Definitely do not create a partition for `/root`.   You are making this a lot more complicated than it needs to be.  If you create enough unpartitioned free space before the installation, the installer will give you a guided option to "install alongside Windows" and Ubuntu will be installed to a single partition where you left the unpartitioned space.

Comment: [What is the root user](https://askubuntu.com/q/507559/590937)

Comment: I have tried to improve the answer to the question about the difference between the `/` and `/root` directories - please have a look if you're still wondering. Thanks karel for the other link and your answer which covers everything else asked about here.

Answer (score 1):

The directions you're following may confuse "/root" (home directory for user root) with root ("/") of the file system.

"/" is the root of the file system (min 8GB for desktop systems)

"/home" is where each user's data live (can get very large)

"/root" is where root's data live (very little to no data actually lives here).  Not worth making a separate mount point.

99% of what you do, you do as a user.  Your data goes in the "/home/username" directory.  Also on real multi-user servers, quotas are setup on "/home" but not on "/root"

A reason some people use a separate mount point for "/home" is to re-install the OS (format, wipe data on "/") while preserving data in "/home" (no format, just mount).

Windows users can do the same thing; "C:" is the OS and "D:" is you data.  Re-install windows by wiping out "C:" but "D:" stays intact.  After reinstall, you can remount "D:" as a folder on "C:" (just like linux mount points).

Personally, I'd just make two partitions:

- ext4 partition, mount point "/" - as much space as possible
- swap partition, 2x RAM

If you want to play with "growing" mount points, use LVM.  Before LVM, admins would use different partitions for mount points.  After LVM, admins could grow a volume as needed across new disks or even between volumes, wherever space was needed.  What you're choosing to do is create separate file systems for each mount point; if your root partition runs out of space, you can't add space without booting from a live CD and using gparted  to resize the partition--that's not easy to do remotely.

All the mount point options that you see will be folders off "/".  I'd recommend a root file system as big as you available space and a swap partition.  Less hassle since you're the only user.

Comment: A swap partition is not needed, instead let the Ubuntu installer create a swap file for you.